# AngularJS: two ng-if or one interpolation?

Tags: angularjs, binding, interpolation, angular-ng-if

A text should be shown depending on condition. One scenario, two ways to implement it.

The first way:

```
<p ng-if="theType == 'type21'">Alert! Special type...</p>
<p ng-if="theType != 'type21'">Chill...</p>
```

The second way:

```
<p>{{theType == 'type21' ? 'Alert! Special type...' : 'Chill...'}}</p>
```

Which one is better? Pros and cons for each way?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `ng-if` - as the documation explains:

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

The second one only checks the condition once but I think `DOM` efficiency is more importent.

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases like those, it's just a matter of preference.

For simple expressions, I would go for the second one. It is just a simple expression and won't show any difference in performance. And if you don't expect `theType` to change, you could use `bindOnce` syntax to prevent further evaluations - improving performance

```
{{::(theType == 'type21' ? 'Alert! Special type...' : 'Chill...')}}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2b5vhgn3/), you can play removing the `::`

For more complex cases, I would rather move interpolation to controller and just using `{{textToShow}}` and I would leave `ng-if` for directives that can be removed, or if DOM structure has to change (here you just change text inside `<p>`, you are not adding new DOM elements)